# Best way to get post info into variables without displaying them in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I am writing a Wordpress plugin and need to go through a number of posts, grab the data from them (for the most part title, permalink, and content), and apply processing to them without displaying them on the page.

**What I've looked at:**

I've looked at [get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) for getting the posts, and then

```
getting title via the_title(),
content via the_content(),
and permalink via the_permalink()
```

Keep in mind that I need this data after all filters had already been applied, so that I get the exact data that would be displayed to the user. Each of the functions above seems to apply all necessary filters and do some postprocessing already, which is great.

**The Problem:**

The problem is all these functions, at least in WP 2.7.1 (latest released version right now) by default just echo everything and don't even return anything back. the_title() actually supports a flag that says do not print and return instead, like so

```
the_title(null, null, false)
```

The other 2, however, don't have such flags, and such inconsistency is quite shocking to me.

I've looked at what each of the_() functions does and tried to pull this code out so that I can call it without displaying the data (this is a hack in my book, as the behavior of the_() functions can change at any time). This worked for permalink but for some reason get_the_content() returns NULL. There has to be a better way anyway, I believe.

**So, what is the best way to pull out these values without printing them?**

Some sample code

```
global $post;
$posts = get_posts(array('numberposts' => $limit));

foreach($posts as $post){
    $title = the_title(null, null, false); // the_title() actually supports a "do not print" flag
    $permalink = apply_filters('the_permalink', get_permalink()); // thanks, WP, for being so consistent in your functions - the_permalink() just prints /s
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content()); // this doesn't even work - get_the_content() returns NULL for me
    print "<a href='$permalink'>$title</a><br>";
    print htmlentities($content, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8"). "<br>";
}
```

P.S. I've also looked at [What is the best method for creating your own Wordpress loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570152/what-is-the-best-method-for-creating-your-own-wordpress-loops) and while it deals with an already obvious way to cycle through posts, the solution there just prints this data.

**UPDATE:** I've opened a ticket with Wordpress about this. http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/9868

Comment: Can you look at the function definition of get_posts and see what it does and use that? Or do these methods just query the db directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I got it all sorted now. Here is the final outcome, for whoever is interested:

- Each post's data can be accessed via iterating through the array returned by get_posts(), but this data will just be whatever is in the database, without passing through any intermediate filters
- The preferred way is to access data using get_the_ functions and them wrapping them in an call to apply_filters() with the appropriate filter. This way, all intermediate filters will be applied.

`apply_filters('the_permalink', get_permalink())`

- the reason why `get_the_content()` was returning an empty string is that apparently a special call to `setup_postdata($post);` needs to be done first. Then `get_the_content()` returns data properly

Thanks everyone for suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

Most functions the_stuff() in WP that echo something have their get_the_stuff() counterpart that *returns* something.

Eg `get_the_title()`, `get_permalink()`...

Comment: Ozh, I've already looked at them and given my reasons for why I think using them in their current form is a kind of a hack (plus, manual applying of filters needs to be done). For example, the_content() currently does additional things to the output of get_the_content(), in addition to simply returning NULL for me. And why is it that the_title() has a "return value and skip printing" flag and the others don't?

Comment: Wordpress devs themselves seem to think that applying filters should be a plugin author's job. http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/7166. Though I disagree, I'll probably end up using it, once I figure out why get_the_content() returns NULL for me. Hack, hack hack.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't find the exact way to do it, you can always use output buffering.

```
<?php
ob_start();
echo "World";
$world = ob_get_clean();
echo "Hello $world";
?>
```

Comment: This is a viable solution and I did think of it as well as last resort but it is indeed another hack. Voted up for the time being.

Comment: If you're going to do this you might want to capture the output of a customized wordpress rss/atom feed and go: $rss = simplexml_load_string($data). Then you can do stuff like this: foreach($rss->item as $item) do_something($item->title);

Comment: Well, actually, the get_posts() function already returns an array of posts, and then for each element in the array I can access $post->post_content, $post->post_title, etc. Now I'm not even sure what I'd need get_the_content() for in the first place. /confused.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you can't do your processing at the time each individual post is posted, or when it's being displayed?

WP plugins generally work on a single post at a time, so there are plenty of hooks for doing things that way.

Comment: Frank, this plugin doesn't operate on individual posts - it's an admin management interface of sorts. Otherwise, I'd just hook into one of the hooks.